# ifelse statement for finding patterns and if true, code a value in another variable

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one column `df$condition` . It contains character strings, like "sunny", "sunshine", "dark", "night" and so on, 1 in each row. Now I want to code those in a second column `df$code`. If the value in df$condition in the row contains "sun", there should be a 1 in `df$code`, if it contains "dark" or "night" there should be a 2. Else if there is anything different or nothing, there should be a 99.

Comment: You should provide a code example!

Comment: Henrik, it is a courtesy to others on the site for you to take more effort when asking a question: as is, you are asking *us* to come up with sample data and expected output structures. Please provide literal data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(x)`) and code you've attempted.

Comment: ... but there are three straight-forward approaches: (1) using named-vectors (`vec <- c("sun"=2,"dark"=7,...)` as a lookup with `df$code <- df$condition[vec]`; (2) using `dplyr::case_when`, as one answer is now suggesting; (3) create a lookup `dict <- data.frame(condition=c("sun","dark"), code=c(2,7))` (one row per unique `condition`) and then doing a merge/join with `merge(mydf, dict, by = "condition", all.x = TRUE)` to get what you want from the data. Good luck.

Comment: Okay sorry, I will put more effort in next time. I thought for most of you this is a really easy task..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have more than one condition, a `case_when` statement is most simple.

```
library(tidyverse)
data = data.frame(V1 = c("sunny", "sunshine", "dark", "night", "cloud"))

data %>%
    mutate(V2 = case_when(
        grepl("sun", V1) ~ 1,
        grepl("dark|night", V1) ~ 2,
        TRUE ~ 99
        )
    )
```

```
        V1 V2
1    sunny  1
2 sunshine  1
3     dark  2
4    night  2
5    cloud 99
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a nested `ifelse` statement:

```
df$code <- with(df, ifelse(grepl("sun", condition), 1, ifelse(grepl("dark|night", condition), 2, 99)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
df <- data.frame(condition=c("sunny","sunshine","dark","night","somethingelse"))


df %>%
  mutate(code = if_else(grepl("sun",condition),1,
                        ifelse(condition=="dark"| condition=="night",2,99)))
```

Output:

```
      condition code
1         sunny    1
2      sunshine    1
3          dark    2
4         night    2
5 somethingelse   99
```